# Write access to Google Drive in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: permissions, mount, google-drive

I added Google drive through online accounts and successfully mounted this drive. I can see the folder in GNOME files and read all the files, but cannot save anything to the drive (i.e. no write access) except through the web interface for google drive. When I look at permissions under properties in Files it says "The permissions of "MyDrive" could not be determined". I would prefer not to mess with syncing programs as I use this drive with other people and windows pc machines. Any way to set write permission to this drive?

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

1. Login to your Google account via browser
2. Choose Manage Google account
3. Go to Security
4. Go to Third-party apps with account access
5. Ensure you have Gnome enabled

Comment: I checked and it looks like gnome has full read and write access